# Highlight Firebase Crashlytics code in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

Seems like there is no plugin for Android Studio to highlight the code spotted in the Firebase Crashlhytics events. I don't see anything related in the official Firebase plugin for IDE neither in the marketplace.
It feels a bit weird copy-pasting code location from the firebase console to the code editor over and over again.

How can I export events from Crashlytics in JSON/RSS format somewhere apart from the Big Query?

Comment: This sounds like it'd be a useful plugin!  Unfortunately, software recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow.  [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be able to help you, though.

Comment: You could render the data from BigQuery to JSON; but still - the IDE probably doesn't care. Any other stack-trace usually tells the filename and the line-number and still requires one to manually navigate there (and often the last one line-number is not the one which one may be looking for). See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data